# Show a markov chain with transition matrix $P$ and a markov chain with matrix $\frac{1}{2}(I+P))$ have the same invariant distribution

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

> Show that if $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a finite state irreducible Markov
>   chain with transition matrix $P$, then a Markov chain with transition
>   matrix $Q= \frac{1}{2}(I+P)$ is irreducible and aperiodic. Moreover,
>   show that the two chains have the same invariant distribution.

I managed to show that the markov chain with transition matrix $Q$ is irreducible and aperiodic, but I'm stuck at showing they have the same invariant distribution.

I've played around a bit with that $\pi_1P=\pi_1$ and $\pi_2( \frac{1}{2}(I+P))=\pi_2$, where $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are the invariant distributions. But I'm not really getting anywhere.

Comment: $\pi_2( \frac{1}{2}(I+P))=\pi_2 \implies \pi_2 P = \pi_2$, since $P$ is irreductible and aperiodic, the stationnary distribution is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\pi_1$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\pi_1P&=\pi_1
\end{aligned}
$$

For $\pi_2$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\pi_2[\frac{1}{2}(I+P)]&=\pi_2 \\
\pi_2[\frac{1}{2}(I+P)]-\pi_2&=0 \\
\pi_2[\frac{1}{2}(I+P)-I]&=0 \\
\pi_2[\frac{1}{2}(P-I)]&=0\\
\frac{1}{2}\pi_2(P-I)&=0 \\
\pi_2(P-I)&=0\\
\pi_2P-\pi_2&=0\\
\pi_2P&=\pi_2
\end{aligned}
$$

I think this can answer your question.